# Are matrix filters white-space-sensitive on IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm using CSS transforms, falling back to the following Matrix transform for IE7 and IE8.

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.0, M12=0.33, M21=-0.33, M22=0.0,sizingMethod='auto expand')
```

This works fine in all versions of IE.  But if I remove the space after each comma, as happens when I minify my CSS, I see a bunch of weird glitches under IE7.  It looks as though the browser is completely ignoring the definitions for various other classes in other parts of the CSS file.

This only affects IE7, and happens whether it's native IE7 or IE9 using the IE7 standards mode.

I can work around this by tweaking my CSS minifier to leave the spaces alone for this rule, but I'd like to understand what is happening.  I assume it's a bug in IE7; am I the first to encounter it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you are the first to encounter it. We encountered this problem just today. You certainly seem to be the first to report it. Scott McGhee [reported](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/ticket/2528170) it a month later. I have not found any other references to this obscure problem.

Your assumption that it is a bug in IE7 is correct; this is unexpected behavior. If you load this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TZjTm/8/) in IE7 or IE7 browser mode, you'll see three orange squares with three X's in it. The first square is 25x25px, the second 50x50px (scaled down from 100x100px and slightly blurred) and the third 100x100px. This is correct behavior. However, if you remove the whitespace character as indicated in the fiddle, you'll see the second and third element are not styled anymore.

My theory is that having a space within a string parameter without leading spaces in the entire parameterslist causes this bug. I have added another method, a blur, to test this conjecture:

```
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius=3, enabled='hello world');
```

If you remove the first space it reproduces the bug, behind the 3. If you also remove the second space, behind hello, it works again. My theory stands unfalsified.

I have not tried this in IE6.